# Make a cookie ignore a specific subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, cookies

I have three subdomains, `cdn.domain`, `private.domain` and `public.domain`. Because the session is shared between domains I'm using `.domain` as domain on the cookie

Running the tests from https://tools.pingdom.com I'm getting this message:

```
Serve static content from a cookieless domain
```

Meaning the cookies set on `domain`, `private.domain` and `public.domain` are being also set for the `cdn.domain`

How can I ignore cookies only on `cdn.domain`?

---

In the server I'm using nginx and rails

---

**EDIT**

On rails this is how I set the sessions cookie

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: 'server_session', domain: :all
```

Passing `domain: :all` generates a cookie for the domain `.domain`

This works for me because the session is kept between domains. But the cookie for the domain `.domain` is also valid to domain `cdn.domain` which is against [PageSpeed recommendations](https://gtmetrix.com/serve-static-content-from-a-cookieless-domain.html) and that is what I am trying to solve

Comment: Could you provide code examples of what your cookies are doing or what you've tried so far?

Comment: @fbelanger Made an edit, if this is not possible thats ok, just submit as a response so I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

You can get another 2nd level domain (e.g. assetsdomain.com) for assets.

Comment: This is an acceptable solution, but would be better if this problem could be solved without a secondary domain

Comment: On HTTP level you can set a cookie per each sub-domain individually but I don't think that Rails session cookie store can do this, you'll probably need to re-implement it yourself.